# How to easily transition from Haskell to Python 3

Tags: python, haskell

So I've written some very pretty Haskell code for my college homework and have found out that they do not plan on supporting Haskell for our homeworks.

I've received an email saying that I should try Python since of all the supported languages it has the most of the "functional".

I've tried some quick code converting to python but am a bit confused whether this really has to look this ugly.

So my Haskell code is

```
transitions = map (map (splitOn ",")) $ map (splitOn "->") $ drop 5 $ input'
```

and my python3 code is

```
transitions = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: y.split(","), x)), map(lambda z: z.split("->"), lined_input[5:])))
```

Since I've written about 10 lines of python so far I was kinda hoping I was missing a nicer way to handle such things.

What bothers me the most is the fact that sometimes i have to use x.split and the map has to be map(f, x).

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend writing Python code like this, since Python makes this sort of thing nicer using list comprehensions and other techniques, but if you really wanted to write it in the functional style you could do something like

```py
import string
from functools import *
from itertools import *

def take(n, iterable): return islice(iterable, n)
def drop(n, iterable): return islice(iterable, n, None)

def splitOn(sep): return partial(string.split, sep=sep)

transitions = imap(splitOn(','), chain(*imap(splitOn('->'), drop(5, input))))
```

As you can tell, this is quite messy.  A more pythonic solution would probably be

```py
transitions = (c for a in drop(5, input)
                 for b in a.split('->')
                 for c in b.split(','))
```

This is even a case where I think regular expressions are acceptable:

```py
import re

def splitOn(*seps): return partial(re.split, '|'.join(re.escape(sep) for sep in seps))

transitions = imap(splitOn(',', '->'), drop(5, input))
```

I'm still able to use functional techniques, such as mapping, generic take/drop, partial application and comprehensions but it comes out a lot cleaner to use more of the python features.  My favorite for the simple case is the simple generator comprehension, but the last one is great if you need more delimiters.

Comment: Thank you. What I really needed was some relevant python code and this is just that. I'll tinkle with your examples a bit to get a feeling of how python feels like.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better way to approach this?

Yes.  Don't try to translate your code from Haskell.  Rewrite it using idiomatic Python.

If you want a functional style, look into `functools`.  For anything involving lists and other iterable objects, consider `itertools` as well (it's lazy, unlike slicing).  But keep in mind that Python is a multi-paradigm programming language, and it takes the position that different problems are better solved using different methods.

Comment: Even though this question seems 'opinion based', I don't believe anybody thinks that you translate from one language to another. The only answer should be yours :)

Comment: How would you write this functionally in python?

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic: I'd probably start by making greater use of generator expressions and list comprehensions.  Don't call `map(lambda: something, something_else)`; that's just ugly.  `map()` is for situations where you *already have* a callable with a simple name.  You can just write `(x.foo() for x in bar)` instead.  Alternatively, use `operator.methodcaller` to avoid the lambdas.

Comment: You should also consider writing a full-blown generator function instead of trying to do this as a one-liner.  That will still give you nice lazy evaluation, but it's much easier to read.

Comment: @Kevin the problem with the `for .. in` is that it changes the  object which is used while the map only returns the changed one

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic: In Python 3.x, `map(x, y)` is *exactly* the same as `(x(z) for z in y)`.